# ffmpeg speed up video but keep same quality

Tags: ffmpeg

I made a timelapse out of an image sequence using ffmpeg and the `copy` codec to disable compression and keep the quality to a max. The timelapse is a bit too long (10 minutes and up) so I tried to use this command to speed it up

`ffmpeg -i timelapse.avi -filter:v "setpts=0.3*PTS" timelapse_fast.avi`

Unfortunately, the quality became that of an online video in 1995. I then tried this

`ffmpeg -i timelapse.avi -filter:v "setpts=0.3*PTS" -vcodec copy timelapse_fast.avi`

It worked but disabled the setpts filter, so the video was not sped up

I also tried the following

`ffmpeg -i timelapse.avi -filter:v "setpts=0.3*PTS" -crf 1 timelapse_fast.avi`

To no avail

Any idea? thanks

Comment: `-q 1` seemed to have done it but there is still a little bit of compression visible

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output from at least one of your commands.

Comment: Cannot copy and filter at the same time. I'd be curious if changing -q  to 0 does anything for you. The filter documentation seems to imply that there is a way to modify frame info without changing the frame content.

Comment: Maybe you could extract every other frame (2x speed), speed up the audio by 2x, then combine the extracted images (use PNGs) and audio track into one video.